# Updating time without refreshing the page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app that displays the current time without have to refresh. 
I'm calling the time below, but when I display it I have to refresh the page to update the time. How do I continuously update the time?

```
function GetTime(){
var today = new Date();
var hour = today.getHours();
var minute = today.getMinutes();

        if (hour>=12){                  //Adding endings
                suffix = "P.M.";}
        else{
                suffix = "A.M.";}


minute = addZero(minute);       //Call addZero function
hour = removeMilitary(hour);    //Call removeMilitary Function

var fullTime = hour + ":" + minute + " " + suffix;  //Combine hour minute and the suffix



        function addZero(number){
                        if (number<10){
                            number = "0" + number;
                        }
                        return number;
        }

        function removeMilitary(hour){ //This function can be removed if desired by user.

            if (hour > 0 && hour <= 12) {
                hour = "" + hour;
            } else if (hour > 12) {
                hour = "" + (hour - 12);
            } else if (hour == 0) {
                hour= "12";
            }
            return hour;
        }
return fullTime;

}
```

Comment: The information given isn't enough to guess what the problem is. Please upload every related codes

Comment: Please Give you HTML code too,thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method.

You can get the time every second, by running your program every 1000 milliseconds:

```
setInterval(GetTime, 1000);
//if you incorporate updating the html 
//within the getTime function
```

or

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("ID_of_the_time_element").innerHTML= getTime();
    //do something else
}, 1000}
```

**Why setInterval at 1000 ms isn't very accurate**

The problem  with that is unless you start the set interval exactly on the second, your program will not change the second exactly on the second. I would recommend you get it more accurate by adjusting the interval to every 100 ms, for example. Then it would update every 100ms, which means that the most your clock will be behind is a tenth of a second.

**A better solution**

Setting an interval every 100ms is ok, but if you want more accuracy, setting it to 10ms isn't necessarily the best option, because repeating a task every 10ms is a pretty large burden on the computer. You could also use find the number of ms until the next second, and then use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=set+timeout) method to wait until the next second arrives and start the set timeout then. You would still have some computational delay(the amount of time between when it gets the number of milliseconds until the next second and it starts the setTimeout), but that's probably a lot less than 100 ms.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an err about it. 

VM109:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
setInterval (async)  
(anonymous)

Any idea why?

Comment: sorry, I used window instead of document. I've updated the examples. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will use the `setInterval()` function.
just add this to your button onclick;

```
setInterval(function(){Document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = getTime},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval (GetTime, 1000) will call your function every second (1000 milliseconds) to get the time. You don't show how you're putting the time on the page, so you'll need to incorporate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I forgot the `setInterval` but someone else already pointed at it, so mix both answers and you're done!

Look at [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Something like the following snippet at the end of your function (instead of `return fulltime` ) should work:

```
...
var myElement = documentGetElementById('mydiv');
myElement.innerHTML = fulltime;
...
```

Of course you need to define some HTML element with `<div id="mydiv"></div>` or whatever you choose.

Comment: Downvote, since you're not answering what the OP wants. The answer should conclude the part that is continuously updating the value and assigning it to the DOM. That's why people including me asked the DOM or other info.

Comment: I assume the OP has some HTML, I still think the downvote is unfair, but whatever

Comment: Edit something whatever it is, I've given you a downvote, but at the same time, you've editted your post. So, there's no reason to leave my downvote on yours anymore

Comment: Edit something so I can take it back :)

Comment: People should take their downvote back once the post has been changed, downvote shouldn't be meant "I do not like your answer, so negative point". It should be always flexible.